# Angular, setting scope variables with two dots

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem when setting scope variables with two dots. See below for my controller and my error.

```
.controller('CreateSubject', function ($scope, factory, $cookieStore, $location, $rootScope){
    $scope.subject.prerequisit = [];
})
```

And I get the error:

> angular.js:13236 TypeError: Cannot set property 'prerequisit' of
>   undefined
>       at new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax that you have to follow is :

```
$scope.subject = { prerequisit : [] };
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the object `subject` first.

Try:

```
.controller('CreateSubject', function ($scope, factory, $cookieStore, $location, $rootScope){ 
    $scope.subject = {};
    $scope.subject.prerequisit = []; 
})
```